# Is it possible to create an android game in unity with no launch icon for the game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a unity game that can only be launched via a third party android app via intents. I am curious to know if I can create unity games without the Unity Launch Icon and if so how can this be achieved. I know this feature is available to native Android platform, not just sure about Unity.

Image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Image of what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Isnt that the only real advantage of the unity pro license to hide the unity logo?:

Comment: Are you talking of the app icon, or about the splash screen?

Comment: @JackMariani i am talking about the app icon (the launcher icon on the phone menu)

Comment: @BugFinder i am talking about the App Icon, the one that launches the game

Comment: I don't think you can do this.

Comment: Afaik you can try and remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from the manifest xml. That should remove `The activity is the initial activity of a task and is listed in the system's application launcher.` (see [intent-filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters))

Comment: @Oto-obongEshiett don't link to your image. embed them in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an Android manifest file in `Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml` to override Unity-created manifest file and remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from your manifest file.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html

You could also build/export your project to a Gradle project and open it in Visual Studio or Android Studio, Edit the manifest file and then build your project there.

https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005695763-Exporting-a-project-to-Gradle-and-building-deploying-on-Android-Studio

Didn't actually test it, but hope it helps.